# mock a Rest service with a resource like "/v1/tenants/?query=dob==1212000;lastName=andy"

Tags: rest, soapui

How do I mock a Rest service with a resource like below path 
`/v1/tenants/?query=dob==1212000;lastName=andy`

I know about the normal query string `?dob=121200&lastName=andy`, but here it's `RSQL PARSER`.

Comment: The mock is based off the resource. How did you define the resource?

Comment: There is a separate services team, they have implemented the service. I just need to mock the service.

Comment: In SoapUI, how did you define the resource?